# Windows Phone 8.1 navigation soft keys covering part of PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins, navigationbar

I have a Phonegap app that when running on windows phone 8.1 the navigation bar soft keys at the bottom of the screen are covering up part of the app. Is there a plugin that allows the screen to be resized when these buttons are shown. I have used a Cordova plugin already called CordovaNavbarPlugin found here: https://github.com/taroquu/CordovaNav... but it did not work as expected. The screen never resized and the event listener that the plugin said to add to record the height when using alert() function always returns zero. has anybody else encountered this issue or know a solution.